# Combine multiple queries into 1 query

Tags: postgresql, performance, subquery, array

I have a `message` table in Postgres 9.4 that contains a `words` field of `array` type, with random words of a message. Currently I have millions of messages:

```
\d messages
                        Table "public.messages"
            Column            |            Type             | Modifiers
------------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------
 id_str                       | character varying(255)      | not null
 feed_id                      | integer                     |
 message                      | character varying(255)      |
 posted_at                    | timestamp without time zone |
 words                        | character varying(255)[]    |
 Indexes:
    "messages_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id_str)
    "index_messages_on_feed_id" btree (feed_id)
    "index_messages_on_feed_id_posted_at" btree (feed_id, posted_at DESC NULLS LAST)
    "index_messages_on_words" gin (words)
```

Now I have an array of words `[A, B, C]`.
I need to find the number of messages that the `words` contains each of the combinations of the list, i.e. `[[A,B], [A,C], [B,C]]`.

Also I have this combination array created outside of the Postgres query already.

I can do this by creating 3 queries:

```
select count(*) from messages where words @> ARRAY['A','B']::varchar[];
select count(*) from messages where words @> ARRAY['A','C']::varchar[];
select count(*) from messages where words @> ARRAY['B','C']::varchar[];
```

Is there a way to do this in one query? And output the result in the following format?

```
A, B, count or [A, B], count
A, C, count
B, C, count
```

**Edit:**

Here's the query I run currently:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7c907/2/0

http://explain.depesz.com/s/Dot

And this one is using Erwin Brandstetter 's method:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7c907/1/0

http://explain.depesz.com/s/pr2

Now assume the messages table has more than 1 Million records, the CTE scan or seq scan in each of the query plan will become very slow.

Comment: To me it sounds like `GROUP BY` is your friend.

Comment: Please *always* provide your version of Postgres. And the actual table definition (`\d tbl` in psql) is superior to describing the table definition with free text.

Comment: What is the mean length of elements in `words`? How many elements on average in `words`? How many unique elements in your search? You mentioned 1000 combinations? That would be ~ 45 distinct words in one search? You can probably make this (substantially) faster, but it will take some time to find 1000 combinations in a million arrays. the fiddles don't seem to work (the site may have problems), please include the query to work with in your question.

Comment: Currently the number of elements in `messages.words` are around 15-20. And I have 50 distinct words, which is 1225 combinations, and this 1225 combinations are pre calculated. so I have this 1225 combination array ready. The problem right now is the performance of the `messages.words` @> '{A, B}'  even with the `gin` index. it still does a seq scan on it. not sure how to improve this.

Comment: The sql fiddle should work, can you try copy and paste the code again? or add or remove the semi colon as end? Sometimes I have to do this to make the fiddle to work.

Answer (score 2):

To get all unique pairs of elements from an array of arbitrary length:

```
WITH a(a) AS (SELECT '{A,B,C,D}'::text[])  -- provide array here
,    i(i) AS (SELECT i FROM a, generate_series(1, array_upper(a.a,1)) i)
SELECT ARRAY[a[i1.i], a[i2.i]] AS pair
FROM   i i1
JOIN   i i2 ON i2 > i1
,      a;
```

You can then join to the `message` table.

Without knowing any details of your setup, my educated guess is that a `LATERAL` join will be fastest as it can use the **GIN index** on `messages.words` - create it if you don't have one yet.

```
WITH a(a) AS (SELECT '{A,B,C,D}'::text[])
,    i(i) AS (SELECT i FROM a, generate_series(1, array_upper(a.a,1)) i)
SELECT p.pair, c.ct
FROM  (
   SELECT ARRAY[a[i1.i], a[i2.i]] AS pair
        , i1.i AS i1, i2.i AS i2
   FROM   i i1
   JOIN   i i2 ON i2 > i1
   ,      a
   ) p
, LATERAL (
   SELECT count(*) AS ct
   FROM   message
   WHERE  words @> p.pair
   ) c
ORDER BY p.i1, p.i2;
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3ae26/4)

Comment: Thanks for the response, and sorry for the confusing in my question. I am using postgres 9.4. And I already have the combination array from my code, ie. ({'A', 'B'}, {'A', 'C'}, {'B','C'}). so I don't have to use postgres to construct this. What I did is I used right join (VALUES #{words_values}) AS t(words) ON messages.words @> t.words" then group by t.words and select count. But this is very slow is I have 1 million messages. Here's the explain: http://explain.depesz.com/s/KlL

Comment: I also tried your solution, it works, but has the same problem, it's very slow when the combination array have over 1000 items, and the messages table is over a million records.  Here's what I did: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6a277/1/0

Comment: I omitted the filters on the messages in the sql fiddle.

Comment: the actual explain: http://explain.depesz.com/s/qXJo is there anyway to use any index instead of the seq scan?

Comment: @ZhaohanWeng: There may be a type mismatch. Are search terms and column exactly the same data type?

Comment: The messages.words is  character varying(255)[] , and I created the values table using (ARRAY['A', 'C']::varchar[]) for each row. I assume the data type is the same?

Comment: @ZhaohanWeng: Almost all the time is spent on a CTE scan, which should not happen. Also, there are predicates you did not mention, yet. I don't think we have the full picture, yet. Can you add the *exact* query you are running *in your question*?

Comment: I have edited my question to include the actual queries.